# Enemy to spawn at specific locations

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, location

I am new to as3, I tried to look for an answer to my question already. For a side scrolling game I have enemies set at certain locations, and I need them to spawn, not just show up once at these specific places in the game. These are excerpts from the timeline code concerning the problem.

```
var enemyList:Array = new Array();

 function addEnemiesToLevel1():void
{
addEnemy (700, 125);
addEnemy (1000, 125);
addEnemy(2405, 125);
addEnemy(3300, -155);
}

if (enemyList.length > 0) 
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < enemyList.length; i++) 
    {
 function addEnemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int):void
 {
var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(xLocation, yLocation);
back.addChild(enemy);
enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved);
enemyList.push(enemy);
 }
```

The enemy is tied to a class file controlling movement towards player

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Enemy extends MovieClip {
        private var xSpeedConst:int = 6;

        public function Enemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int) {
            // constructor code
            x = xLocation;
            y = yLocation;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }

        public function loop(e:Event):void {

                x -= xSpeedConst;   
             }

        public function removeSelf():void {
            trace("remove enemy");
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }

    }
```

}

The enemy is also set for collisions so I don't want to change the code too much, since I might spoil something. If I have to add Timer, please tell me where exactly, because I already tried that and failed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I recommend not coding in the timeline, a working example timer setup in the timeline would look like this:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(2000,0);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, createEnemy);

function createEnemy(e:TimerEvent):void{
    //create a new enemy, pass the x and y you want (xPos and yPos here)
    //var xPos:int, yPos:int
    var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy( xPos, yPos );
    back.addChild(enemy);
}

timer.start();
```

You could also do a similar setup in your class files if you are generating enemies there. Again, doing this in the timeline will much harder to maintain and debug.

Comment: Thank you! That works great. Can you tell me how would i assign the enemies to come out from  several x and y positions not just one?. Do i need to delete the add enemies to level 1 function? How would i control them on level 2? I am sorry they will not let me post questions in the regular answers box, so I have to post with these miniature letters here.

Comment: Well I'm not sure exactly how you would want to do it, but you could probably just have an array of points you wanted them to spawn from, then loop the array and do `var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy( myArray[i].x, myArray[i].y );` that would be on solution.

Comment: Can I add 2 more locations on top of this code: var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy( xPos, yPos ); or that is impossible?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. Do you want to make 2 more enemies at different locations or do you want the enemy you are making to go to 1 of 3 possible locations?

Comment: Sorry you are right. I like to have 2 more of the same enemy spawning from 2 other locations, total of 3 at the same time. I already setup the first one, so if I can add the other two in top of ( var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy( xPos, yPos )) code, would be great.

Comment: yeah just duplicate that new enemy line 2 more times and change the x and y parameters.

Comment: Like this?  var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy( 900, 125); new Enemy( 1500, 125 ); It does not work

Comment: Ah I should have explicitly said you need unique variable names (assumed that was a given) Do this: `var enemy2:Enemy = new Enemy( 900, 125);` and `var enemy3:Enemy = new Enemy( 1500, 125 );`

Comment: It works actually. Thank you so much I had to do back.addChild(enemy2); Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again! I added the enemies successfully and everything is fine on level 1. On level 2 however I get an error that flash is looking for the enemies from the first level. They are inside an MC. Do you know how I can remove them so it does not look for them?